# Xamarin File load error

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Ok, this is a bit weird but hopefully there is a simple fix.
So when i go to Add/New Item on my PCL folder click on Xamarin Forms then choose:

ContentPage (XAML) and name it (as per usual) my solution explorer loads with the NewView.xaml.cs (class) and the NewView.xaml loads on the main view instead of in the Solution Explorer. Image supplied to make understanding better.

Currently I have created a template folder with a copy of the mainPage and add new pages that way but would love a fix, as if i close my xaml file i can not find again.

[image: Xaml fix needed]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with templates; you need to open the Visual Studio installer and repair it, and then update Visual Studio and the Xamarin software development kit..

Comment: I had Visual Studio originally then installed the Xamarin package after i wish i uninstalled and downloaded the whole thing from scratch.

Comment: I will when i have free time, just in the middle of development and do not want to break flow or the environment. When i repaired from launcher tool, wouldnt let me add files to my project but after a few repairs where back to normal.Crazy!

Comment: Solution: was to stop using Shared Projects and create in .Net Standard (PCL).